# Question about "working" trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, opportunity, event

I really need help understanding a trigger i'm trying to code.

I want a trigger who willpopulate the field "What" (field label: "Related to") of an event with the Account's related opportunity when an event is created or updated.

The Trigger is working when I create or update an event in the sandbox. But if I remove the try/catch block, it doesn't anymore for *before insert* (*before update* works fine), since an exception is raised:

*execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject*.

Why does the trigger have intended behavior with the try/catch block? Any way of removing it?

I know i'm new to coding apex, and did query in a loop, etc. sorry in advance. Best practices tips are appreciated, but please focus on my question.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

My trigger code:

```
//logic:

//if name of event is "discovery meeting" or "follow up meeting"
//query account ID on event and store in a variable
//query opportunity related to account
//populate the whatid field of the event with the opportunity ID

trigger Populate_Event on Event (before insert, before update) {

for (Event Meeting : Trigger.new) {

    if ((Meeting.subject == 'Discovery Meeting')||(Meeting.subject == 'Follow-up Meeting')){
 
        ID account_id = meeting.accountid;
     
        //need to catch the exception since before insert will fail
        try {
            
            opportunity opp = [select id FROM Opportunity Where AccountId = :account_id];
            meeting.whatid = opp.id;
}    
        catch (System.QueryException e) {

            System.debug('Catch Query exception');
}
}    
}
}
```

Comment: When is `meeting.accountid` populated?  It sounds like either triggers are not executing in the order you expect or objects are inserted asynchronously by the app.

Comment: The field event.accountId is not updateable unfortunately :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) avoid SQL in for loop, very bad practice, it's called [bulkify your code](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices) the use of *Map* will help you ;-)

2) Even if it will return 1 opportunity only, always use a list, Salesforce always returns you a list of opportunity, then try to assign the first element of the list to your **opp**. That's why you are getting *List has no rows for assignment to SObject*. so transform :

```
opportunity opp = [select id FROM Opportunity Where AccountId = :account_id];
```

**to**

```
opportunity[] opp = [select id FROM Opportunity Where AccountId = :account_id];
```

3) AccountId is populated automatically from the UI when you create an event from a contact now from test class I think you will need to populate that yourself (to confirm), probably make sure in your trigger that accountid is not blank before to execute the rest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and tips. I will read the info and work on that.

Comment: I used a list like you suggested, but I now get "list index out of bounds" exception. I know for certain there IS an opportunity record..

Comment: @JeanCadieux if you are running in test context you have to create your own test data. Prod data is not visible by default during tests

Comment: @Eric Thanks, I already did. Unfortunately that's not my question :/

Comment: @JeanCadieux did you debug the results of your query? Is it returning any records

Comment: Can you update your question with your new code?

Comment: @CloudNinja The code above  fails if i change it to _opportunity[] opp = [select id FROM Opportunity Where AccountId = :account_id];_ and _meeting.whatid = opp[0].id;_. It raises "list index out of bounds" exception

Comment: @CloudNinja I'm trying to understand why the trigger is working with the try/catch block and not without.